# How to send Map as a requestBody in rest call from java

Tags: java, json, rest, spring-boot, spring-annotations

I have a rest endpoint which takes RequestParam and RequestBody as a parameter. In a client side i am using javax client to invoke this rest endpoint but getting a problem as response code 405 is coming from server.

Here is springBoot restEndpoint code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/run", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json")
    public ReportRunResult runBackendCall(@RequestParam(name = "clientName", required = true) String reportName,
                                     @RequestBody Map<String, ReportParameter> formParams) {
        return service.runReport(reportName, formParams);
    }
```

this is how i am calling this endpoint from client:

```
 public ReportRunResult runBackendCall(String name, Map<String, ReportParameter> parameters) {

  ReportRunResult reportResponse = null;
        WebTarget target = RestClientBuilder.clientBuilder(RestClientBuilder.buildSSLContext(), 3000, 10000).build()
                .target(serverURL.get() + "/run?reportName=" + name);

        Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
        Response response = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).post(Entity.json(parameters));

        reportResponse = response.readEntity(ReportRunResult.class);
        log.info("response. " + response.getStatus() + " ");   
    }
```

I don't understand why server sending response 405 Do i need to convert Map(parameters) into json string in Entity.json(parameters)); ?

Answer (score 1):

The status code `405` tells you `Method Not Allowed` so maybe there is an issue with your [HTTP-Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes).

There is also a failure in your code in the `WebTarget` you're using the `reportName` as `RequestParam` but the REST-Service wants the `clientName` as `RequestParam`.

So change

```
@RequestParam(name = "clientName", required = true)
```

to

```
@RequestParam(name = "reportName", required = true)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use JSONObject like this :

```
new JSONObject(map)
```

PS: the map should be of type `Map<String,String>`